# password error after upgrade to 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade, password

I have upgraded a local install of magento 1.6 to 1.9
the magento install is on a windows server so I can't run mage script. I upgraded manually by copy and paste the magento 1.9.1 system files replacing the old one.

I didn't expect this to work, but it did! Now that I have and upgraded version of magento I have password error for both customers and admin users.
This is not the "usual" cookie or session issue. I have understand this happens due to the different ways password are generated in magento 1.6 and 1.9: the salt is no longer 2 character string but 32.
if I manually generate a new encrypted password staring from the same old non encrypted pw value and update this in the database I can correctly login.
I made a test with this code in a getpw.php file in the magento root:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
## For magento1.7 or Earlier var
//$_HASH_SALT_LENGTH = 2;
## For magento1.8 and magento1.9
$_HASH_SALT_LENGTH = 32;
#Generate admin password 
$password = "my-old-password-value";
echo $adminPass = Mage::helper('core')->getHash($password, $_HASH_SALT_LENGTH);
?>
```

I run this script and then copy the new pw in the database. This work fine both for user and admin. 
The issue is that I have to now the old non encrypted password and obviously  this is true only for mine account.
There is a way to update all the password to the new format? I assume magento upgrade script takes care of it in some way... How can I do the same via SQL or PHP?

UPDATE:
HAs been pointed out question [70459](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70459/admin-updated-user-passwords-not-working-after-upgrade-magento-1-7-1-9) as a possible duplicate of this one.
I think it is not a duplicate of mine because in that case the old passwords with 2 character salt work and the updated one no. In my case it is the opposite: if I manually change the pw it update correctly, but if I don't update the user get "wrong password" error.
Moreover I don't have any database related issue in VARCHAR length like in the case of the question  [70459](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70459/admin-updated-user-passwords-not-working-after-upgrade-magento-1-7-1-9).
I need to understand why the passwords with 2 characters salt are no more recognized and how to automatically update all the admins and customers pws with a one click script.

UPDATE 2:
I have also read the [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/1rndjj/did_ce18_change_the_way_magento_stores_hashed/) suggested in in the previously mentioned similar question. It ends whit this simple statement:

> However, Magento should still correctly recognize old passwords.

So the issue I'm experiencing is a bug caused by the upgraded process. And not by a wrong configuration of a database field link in the case of the other question.
I'll really appreciate any advice on how to fix this issue.

Comment: if you have now your password then why you cannot  reset  password.

Comment: please try this `require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);Mage::app('admin');
Mage::getModel('admin/user')
->loadByUsername($adminUSerName)
->setPassword($password)
->save();
`

Comment: about the first comment: I need to update passwords for all the customers (thousands) and I don't want customers had to reset their how pw or to notify them a new pw. I just want to make their old pw to work properly. About the second comment: your script needs I know the password to be set, am I right?

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I've updated my question to explain why it is not a duplicate of the one you pointed out. Do you have any advice?